# OpenLayers 5: To display the label for a point

Tags: openlayers, geojson, geodjango

In my project there are two GeoJSON point layer, both has the same attribute '*name*'. I would like to use this attribute for labeling all points.

I've found [this similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/137569/72195) but it is for OpenLayers 3. 
However I've used a part of code:

```
var getText = function(feature) {
    var text = feature.get('name');
    return text;
};

var style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 7,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(200,200,200,1.0)',
            width: 3,
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
          })
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
          text: getText(feature),
          font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
          placement: 'point',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#fff'}),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#000', width: 2}),
      }),
  });

var addPointsSource = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '{% url 'points_geojson' %}',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: style,
});

var freezedPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '{% url 'points_freezed_geojson' %}',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: style,
});
```

This is an example of GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Napoli",
        "publishing_date": "2019-07-30T08:14:57",
        "updating_date": "2019-07-30T08:15:15.317",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-30T08:15:15.317",
        "pk": "1"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          14.254760740203487,
          40.855370527204315
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "New York",
        "publishing_date": "2019-07-30T08:15:15",
        "updating_date": "2019-07-30T08:15:49.464",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-30T08:15:49.464",
        "pk": "2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -73.99017332954408,
          40.738933236426014
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Petra",
        "publishing_date": "2019-07-30T08:15:49",
        "updating_date": "2019-07-30T08:19:56.621",
        "timestamp": "2019-07-30T08:19:56.621",
        "pk": "3"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          35.44249534113302,
          30.33036084747055
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I use that code I see this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: style is not defined

My map is based on GeoDjango and I know that my knowledge of javascript are very very low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`style` is defined in the code you have provided, so the error may be in the code for `getText(feature)` which you haven't shown.  It is more efficient to define a single style and use a style function to set the text for each feature:

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
          radius: 7,
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(200,200,200,1.0)',
            width: 3,
          }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)'
          })
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
          font: 'bold 11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
          placement: 'point',
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#fff'}),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#000', width: 2}),
      }),
  });

var styleFunction = function(feature) {
  style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
  return style;
}

var addPointsSource = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '{% url 'points_geojson' %}',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: styleFunction,
});

var freezedPoints = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '{% url 'points_freezed_geojson' %}',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: styleFunction,
});
```